# If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $f([a,b])\subseteq [a,b]$ then it has a unique fixed-point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Prove or give a counter-example for the following sentence:

If $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and $f([a,b])\subseteq [a,b]$ then $f$ has a **unique** fixed-point in $[a,b]$.

---

I am having hard time trying to prove it and to find a counter-example.

(Note: since $f([a,b])\subseteq [a,b]$ and since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ we know that $f$ has a fixed-point in $[a,b]$ but we do not know wether it is **unique**)

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: The  unique  fixed  point  exists  when $f([a,b])$  is  a  proper  subset  of $[a,b]$ . If not uniqueness  is  not  necessary,  say   for  the  identity  function  where  $f([a,b])=[a,b]$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest counterexample I can conceive is

$$f(x)=x$$

Then every point is a fixed point.

Comment: I simply didn't got that, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly false. Just take $f$ to be the identity function and $a<b$. Clearly $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and $f([a,b])=[a,b]\subseteq[a,b]$ and all points are fixed points.